# Matrix transformation into block off-diagonal form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Consider the 4-by-4 matrix $\boldsymbol M = \boldsymbol M_0 + \boldsymbol M_1$, where

$\boldsymbol M_0 = \alpha \left( \begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 \end{matrix} \right)$ and  $\boldsymbol M_1 = \beta \left( \begin{matrix}
  0 & \gamma & 0 & -\gamma^{*} \\
  \gamma^{*} & 0 & -\gamma^{*} & 0 \\
  0 & \gamma & 0 & -\gamma^{*} \\
  \gamma & 0 & -\gamma & 0 \\
 \end{matrix} \right)$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants and $\gamma = \gamma_x + i \gamma_y$ is complex.

Is it possible to unitary transform $\boldsymbol M$ into block off-diagonal form $\boldsymbol M_B$?

Namely, I want to find a unitary transform $\boldsymbol U$ so that I can write down $\boldsymbol M_B = \boldsymbol U \boldsymbol M \boldsymbol U^{*}$ (here $\boldsymbol U^{*}$ is the conjugate transpose).

Explicitly, the required block off-diagonal matrix is (in general form)

$\boldsymbol M_B = \left( \begin{matrix}
  0 & \boldsymbol Q \\
  \boldsymbol Q^{*} & 0
 \end{matrix} \right)$ where $\boldsymbol Q = \left( \begin{matrix}
  Q_z & Q_x - i Q_y \\
  Q_x + i Q_y & -Q_z
 \end{matrix} \right)$

Is there a general recipe to find such a unitary transformation matrix $\boldsymbol U$ which leads to the block off-diagonal form, $\boldsymbol M \to \boldsymbol M_B$?

Comment: What do you mean by "transform"?  Are you looking for a similar matrix?  If not, what are you trying to do?  Are you trying to compute a determinant?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I try to find a unitary transform matrix to allow me to pass from my original matrix to its block-off diagonal form. I am not interested in determinants (unless it helps to acheive this goal!). I tried to edit the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this $4 \times 4$ matrix is the answer.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
-I & 0 & I & 0 \\
0 & -I & 0 & I
\end{pmatrix}$$